# Use of \foreach and \csname<macro name>\endcsname together

Tags: macros, foreach

When I compile this minimum LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{report}

\def\defMacro#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\useMacro#1{\csname#1\endcsname}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {0,1,...,10}{
\defMacro{number:\n}{\n}
}


\useMacro{number:8}
\end{document}
```

I obtain no PDF output. What do I mistake?

Comment: The `etoolbox` package provides `\csdef` and `\csuse` which do the same as `\defMacro` and `\useMacro`. LaTeX itself defines `\@namedef` and `\@nameuse`. The `\csuse` macro takes care not to define the given macro (equal to `\relax`) if it doesn't exists. It expands to nothing in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\foreach` loop content is executed in a group for each iteration, therefore the definition is only local. You would need to add `\global` in front of `\defMacro`.

The reason the `\useMacro` is not causing an error is because `\csname` has the side effect that the resulting macro is defined equal to `\relax` if is was undefined before.

Comment: I changed the second line in
\def\defMacro#1#2{\expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname{#2}}. Thanks

Comment: @Azoun: Note that this of course makes all `\defMacro` definitions global, which might be an issue dependent on the use. For your own private macros this shouldn't be an issue, but I wouldn't do that for package code.

Comment: I'm just beginning to learn TeX...so I'm just playing. Many thanks for the advice